# Invalid credentials for magento/module-store

Tags: magento2, composer

After creating my `auth.json` file  and adding the credentials:

```
{
  "http-basic": {
    "repo.magento.com": {
      "username": "publickey",
      "password": "privatekey"
    }
  }
}
```

and doing a `composer install`, and I am receiving this message:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Package operations: 379 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing magento/module-store (100.2.8): Downloading (connecting...)

  [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]                                                                                        
  Invalid credentials for 'https://repo.magento.com/archives/magento/module-store/magento-module-store-100.2.8.0.zip', aborting
```

any idea what am i missing ? 
Thnx

Comment: can you please check auth.json permission.

Comment: also check credentials

Comment: @AnasMansuri See: `-rw-rw-r--  1 www-data www-data    125 Sep  4 12:07 auth.json`

Comment: @RkRathod I am 100% sure the credentials are correct :)